# Reading with cat: Stop when not receiving data

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, cat

Is there any way to tell the `cat` command to stop reading when not receiving any data? maybe with some "timeout" that specifies for how long no data is incoming.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `read`?

Comment: cat $fifo | while nc ...

Answer (score 7):

There is a `timeout(1)` command. Example:

```
timeout 5s cat /dev/random
```

Dependening on your circumstances. E.g. you run bash with -e and care normally for the exit code.

```
timeout 5s cat /dev/random || true
```

Comment: and this would cancel cat if there's no input from /dev/random for more than 5s?

Comment: no, this will just stop cat. You can then analyze output to see if something is there.

Comment: but i want to stop cat just if there's no more data coming from /dev/random for more than x seconds

Comment: Good to know about `timeout`, but note that it is a _GNU_ utility (in other words: not part of the POSIX utility set, and therefore not available on all platforms).

Comment: @MichałŠrajer nice idea, unfortunetly this leads to exit code 124 from timeout :)

Answer (score 5):

`cat` itself, no. It reads the input stream until told it's the end of the file, blocking for input if necessary.

There's nothing to stop you writing your *own* `cat` equivalent which will use `select` on standard input to timeout if nothing is forthcoming fast enough, and exit under those conditions.

In fact, I once wrote a `snail` program (because a snail is slower than a cat) which took an extra argument of characters per second to slowly output a file <sup>(a)</sup>.

So `snail 10 myprog.c` would output `myprog.c` at ten characters per second. For the life of me, I can't remember why I did this - I suspect I was just mucking about, waiting for some real work to show up.

Since you're having troubles with it, here's a version of `dog.c` (based on my afore-mentioned `snail` program) that will do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

static int dofile (FILE *fin) {
    int ch = ~EOF, rc;
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval tv;

    while (ch != EOF) {
        // Set up for fin file, 5 second timeout.

        FD_ZERO (&fds); FD_SET (fileno (fin), &fds);
        tv.tv_sec = 5; tv.tv_usec = 0;
        rc = select (fileno(fin)+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (rc < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "*** Error on select (%d)\n", errno);
            return 1;
        }
        if (rc == 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "*** Timeout on select\n");
            break;
        }

        // Data available, so it will not block.

        if ((ch = fgetc (fin)) != EOF) putchar (ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int argp, rc;
    FILE *fin;

    if (argc == 1)
        rc = dofile (stdin);
    else {
        argp = 1;
        while (argp < argc) {
            if ((fin = fopen (argv[argp], "rb")) == NULL) {
                fprintf (stderr, "*** Cannot open input file [%s] (%d)\n",
                    argv[argp], errno);
                return 1;
            }
            rc = dofile (fin);
            fclose (fin);
            if (rc != 0)
                break;
            argp++;
        }
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Then, you can simply run `dog` without arguments (so it will use standard input) and, after five seconds with no activity, it will output:

```
*** Timeout on select
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Actually, it was called `slowcat` but `snail` is much nicer and I'm not above a bit of minor revisionism if it makes the story sound better :-)

Comment: puuuh I think I don't get it. I'm not that common with c.

Comment: @Kai, check the update, I've coded up a `dog` program based on `snail` that does what you need.

Comment: while running `dog`, if I type one letter per second (no return) then I get timeout anyway. In other words - select see line-buffered data.

Comment: ok this looks very good. how can I use this with anything like cat? for example I'd like to say "dog /dev/input/event0"

Comment: Michał, yes, line buffering will affect that in which case you should use `setvbuf` to make it unbuffered.

Comment: @Kai, provided it's in your path, it should work identically to `cat`. Just give the file name you want to dog, and voila :-)

Comment: @Kai, you'll need to be more specific. "I tried X but without any success" is not the most verbose/eloquent bug report I've ever seen :-) What is the errant behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: I get the response: "*** cannot open input file [/dev/input/mouse0]"

Comment: @Kai, that has little to do with the program. I suspect that either the file doesn't exist or the permissions may be wrong for it. If you modify the main as per my update, it should give you the error number.

Answer (score 2):

[`mbuffer`](https://www.mankier.com/1/mbuffer), with its `-W` option, works for me.

I needed to sink `stdin` to a file, but with an idle timeout:

- I did not need to actually concatenate multiple sources (but perhaps there are ways to use `mbuffer` for this.)
- I did not need any of `cat`'s possible output-formatting options.
- I did not mind the progress bar that `mbuffer` brings to the table.

I did need to add `-A /bin/false` to suppress a warning, based on a suggestion in the linked man page.  My invocation for copying `stdin` to a file with 10 second idle timeout ended up looking like

```
mbuffer -A /bin/false -W 10 -o ./the-output-file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for timeout-cat:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void timeout(int sig) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        int sec = 0; /* seconds to timeout (0 = no timeout) */
        int c;

        if (argc > 1) {
                sec = atoi(argv[1]);
                signal(SIGALRM, timeout);
                alarm(sec);
        }
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
                alarm(0);
                putchar(c);
                alarm(sec);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It does basically the same as paxdiablo's dog. 
It works as a `cat` without an argument - catting the stdin. As a first argument provide timeout seconds.

One limitation (applies to dog as well) - lines are line-buffered, so you have n-seconds to provide a line (not any character) to reset the timeout alarm. This is because of readline.

**usage**:

instead of potentially endless:

```
cat < some_input > some_output
```

you can do compile code above to timeout_cat and:

```
./timeout_cat 5 < some_input > some_output
```

Comment: sorry but I don't get it working. I tried "./timeout-cat /dev/input/event4 5" (event4 is my keyboard)

Comment: no, it behaves as `cat` command without any argument. the only argument is a timeout.

Comment: what is the difference to paxdiablo's solution? is it just a question of design?

Comment: I tried "./timeout_cat 5 /dev/input/mouse0" -> just terminates after 5 seconds without any output before or afterwards...

Comment: @Kai: (what difference) It does more or less the same, but in different way. We all are here to learn, right?

Comment: @Kai: (timeout_cat 5 /dev/...) timeout_cat is reading only stdin, not files provided by argument. So, `timeout_cat 2 filename` ignores filename and reads from keyboard. You must use redirection: `timeout_cat 2 < filename`. See "usage:" in post.

Comment: ok this way it starts but after about a seconds just terminates

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider tail -f --pid
I am assuming that you are reading some file and when the producer is finished (gone?) you stop.

Example that will process /var/log/messages until watcher.sh finishes.

```
./watcher.sh&
tail -f /var/log/messages --pid $! | ... do something with the output
```

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately it's not on my `tail`s. I expect it's Gnu-only.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue of cat command blocking while reading on tty port via adb shell but did not find any solution (timeout command was also not working). Below is the final command I used in my python script (running on ubuntu) to make it non-blocking. Hope this will help someone.

```
bash_command = "adb shell \"echo -en 'ATI0\\r\\n' > /dev/ttyUSB0 && cat /dev/ttyUSB0\" & sleep 1; kill $!"
response = subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', bash_command])
```

Comment: I don't know how to detect the lack of data, but wouldn't use use a signal to control `cat`?

Answer (score -1):

Simply cat then kill the cat after 5 sec.

```
cat xyz & sleep 5; kill $!
```

Get the cat output as a reply after 5 seconds

```
reply="`cat xyz & sleep 5; kill $!`"
echo "reply=$reply"
```

Comment: What if the data-generating process outputs for some unspecified time (could be a minute, could be a day), then stops? You'd only get the first five seconds - even though the source would still be outputting data.

Comment: Yes, that's the fact. So you must use the maximum possible timeout with this logic. I.e. when the reply will be useless for you.

Comment: The point is, the maximum possible timeout is not known; and getting a notification "the process has probably finished outputting data sometime in the last week (or maybe not, maybe we just killed it instead)" is worse than useless.

Comment: In other words: "I have a car with a tank full of gas and an engine running. Tell me when I've run out of gas." "Okay, just kill the engine after a fixed timeout and pretend that was the correct moment." See? The timeout will, most probably, be way too low (there's still plenty of fuel) or way too high (fuel was already depleted a long time ago); it's unlikely that you'd guess it to be correct ahead of time.

Comment: You may redirect the output from cat to some file and poll that file from time to time to see what has come out. Then you may not use a timeout but kill the cat when you are satisfied with the reply. Actually I think my reply is for the question at the top of the page from Kai. Yours is another case.

Comment: "Is there any way to tell the cat command to stop reading **when not receiving any data**? maybe with some "timeout" that specifies **for how long no data is incoming**." "Just wait for a moment, blindly assume that no more data is coming, and be done with it" Suuure, that answers the question. It's not a very useful answer, and it's going to give wrong results most of the time, but it *answers* the question.